# Set the return type of toObject method

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I'm attempting to set the return type of the `toObject` method in Mongoose, although I'm not sure if that's possible.

With generics, it's possible to set the properties of a `Document` object, that is returned from a query with Mongoose, but the getters and setters of those objects usually run many validation codes when accessed, which is something I'd like to avoid in some cases.

Those `Document` objects have the `toObject` method that returns an equivalent anonymous object, which is what I'm using, but those returned objects have the `any` type. I'd like to set the type of those objects in the `Schema` or `Model` definition, so I wouldn't have to resort to type assertion every time I do a query.

Currently my code looks like this:

```js
import mongoose, { Schema, Document } from 'mongoose'

interface User {
    username: string,
    email:    string,
    password: string,
}

const UserSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    email:    { type: String, required: true },
    password: { type: String, required: true },
})

const UserModel = mongoose.model<User & Document>('User', UserSchema)

export { User, UserModel }
```

With this I can perform a query with the following code:

```js
const userDocument = await UserModel.findById(id)
const userObj      = userDocument && userDocument.toObject()
```

While `userDocument` is of the type `User extends Document`, `userObj` is of the type `any`. I'd like to set it to be of the type `User`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly the toObject method in Mongoose is typed as "any" which means the only options would be to augment "toObject" method and override the typings | OR | to type userObj with a colon.

This is the signature of toObject in mongoose typings.

```
 toObject(options?: DocumentToObjectOptions): any;
```

the easy work around is to do this...

```
const userObj: undefined | User = userDocument && userDocument.toObject()
```

Hope this helps, i know this isn't an "ideal" solution but i would say take it up with Typescript gitter or DefinitelyTyped mongoose team for them to fix the typings internally.

Let me know if there's anything else.